# Initial conditions of transient behavior of a driven oscillation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

For a driven oscillation

$$X_G = A_0e^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}t} cos(\omega_v t + \phi) + A cos(\omega_d t - \delta),$$

where $A_0$ and $\phi$ are determined by the initial conditions $x_0$ and $\dot x_0$

If at $t=0, \dot x_0 = 0$  at $x=0$ does it means $A_0$ and $\phi = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. Just to show for the initial condition of position we will have:

$$A_0 \cos(\phi)+A\cos(\delta)=0$$

So obviously $A_0$ and $\phi$ are not $0$ (they depend on $A$ and $\delta$). This is just one equation though and we cannot yet solve it, you must differentiate your equation and plug in $t=0$ to obtain the second equation and then solve for $A_0$ and $\phi$.